SVG stroke showing unwanted dot. Not seen in figma
Photo of the dot
When I export a SVG from Figma, it gives me this tiny unwanted dot in the stroke of a specific path.
<svg width="33" height="38" viewBox="0 0 33 38" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M29.4874 5.96259C29.185 4.56022 28.3062 3.5063 27.0896 2.95241C26.005 2.4586 24.8396 2.44183 23.8865 2.56268C21.9671 2.80607 19.8967 3.73641 18.2979 4.85872C18.1219 4.98229 17.613 5.20669 16.6039 5.39113C15.6562 5.56436 14.4991 5.66288 13.2344 5.7034C10.7078 5.78434 8.0053 5.62774 6.16576 5.5055C5.32871 5.44988 4.51956 5.81779 4.01123 6.48514C3.50291 7.15249 3.36318 8.0303 3.63917 8.8225C4.71631 11.9142 5.5 15.2666 5.5 18.5C5.5 23.1366 4.75649 27.3225 2.81385 30.8244C2.33564 31.6865 2.40866 32.7491 3.0003 33.5376C3.59194 34.3261 4.59172 34.6933 5.55309 34.4752C10.7908 33.287 17.524 30.4418 22.595 25.8288C27.7383 21.1501 31.3214 14.4693 29.4874 5.96259ZM29.4874 5.96259L27.0483 6.48844L29.4874 5.96258C29.4874 5.96258 29.4874 5.96259 29.4874 5.96259Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_43_112)" stroke="#63310E" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear_43_112" x1="16.2359" y1="5" x2="16.2359" y2="32.0372" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#E76B13"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#813C0B"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>

I am trying to make a logo for a little group called Ducky. I expected it to show a stroke as it was in Figma.
How it looked

It was caused by a small segment you added in the svg code
    <svg width="33" height="38" viewBox="0 0 33 38" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M29.4874 5.96259C29.185 4.56022 28.3062 3.5063 27.0896 2.95241C26.005 2.4586 24.8396 2.44183 23.8865 2.56268C21.9671 2.80607 19.8967 3.73641 18.2979 4.85872C18.1219 4.98229 17.613 5.20669 16.6039 5.39113C15.6562 5.56436 14.4991 5.66288 13.2344 5.7034C10.7078 5.78434 8.0053 5.62774 6.16576 5.5055C5.32871 5.44988 4.51956 5.81779 4.01123 6.48514C3.50291 7.15249 3.36318 8.0303 3.63917 8.8225C4.71631 11.9142 5.5 15.2666 5.5 18.5C5.5 23.1366 4.75649 27.3225 2.81385 30.8244C2.33564 31.6865 2.40866 32.7491 3.0003 33.5376C3.59194 34.3261 4.59172 34.6933 5.55309 34.4752C10.7908 33.287 17.524 30.4418 22.595 25.8288C27.7383 21.1501 31.3214 14.4693 29.4874 5.96259Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_43_112)" stroke="#63310E" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_43_112" x1="16.2359" y1="5" x2="16.2359" y2="32.0372" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop stop-color="#E76B13"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#813C0B"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>

To be specific the segment

" L27.0483 6.48844 "


Thanks, don't know why Figma added that lol
